# How to return a value returned from a function of its not undefined else "do nothing" in JS

Tags: javascript, function

So I have 2 functions like

> var a = function () {
>
> ```
>   // returns something or returns nothing
> ```
>
> }
>
> var b = function () {
>
> ```
>   //call a() here and return value returned from a() if a() returns something, else continue with execution of b()
> ```
>
> }

I know I can have a variable store returned value and use it but what is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it the principle of an `if` ?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a simpler way to do this than storing the return value in a variable and checking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function b() {
    // Return the value returned from a() if it returned something.
    var result = a();
    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
    }

    // continue with execution of b.
}
```

It won't distinguish the `undefined` that results from

```
return;
```

from the `undefined` that results from

```
return undefined;
```

but if you know `a()` always returns a value besides `undefined` when it intentionally returns a value you can rely on `!== undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about what `a()` returns.  Just assign that return value to a local variable, do your other stuff and then return that local variable.  If `a()` had a return value, it will be in that local variable and get returned.  If `a()` didn't have a return value, the value of the local variable will be `undefined` which is what you will return from `b()`.  It works either way.

```
var b = function () {
     var retVal = a();

    // do other stuff

    return(retVal);   // works whether a() had a return value or not
}
```

I wasn't sure in your question.  If you wanted to test the return value of `a()` to see if it had a return value, then you can do this:

```
var b = function () {
     var retVal = a();
     if (retVal === undefined) {
         // do one thing
     } else {
         // do another thing
     }

    // do other stuff

    return(retVal);   // works whether a() had a return value or not
}
```